# Search functionality rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a current implementation that allows me to filter my search results by category name

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bike_categories
  has_many :bikes, through: :bike_categories
end

class BikeCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Holds bike_id and category_id to allow multiple categories to be saved per image, as opposed to storing an array of objects in one DB column
  belongs_to :bike
  belongs_to :category
end

class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bike_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :bike_categories
end

Model

def self.search(params)
  includes_categories(params[:name])
end

def self.includes_categories(category_names)
  joins(:categories)
  .where(categories: { name: category_names })
  .group('bikes.id')
  .having("count(*) = ?", category_names.size)
end
```

So if i have the following data

```
Bike
id: 1 title: 'Bike 1'
id: 2 title: 'Bike 2'

category
id: 1 name: 'Mens'
id: 2 name: 'Womens'
id: 3 name: 'Mountain Bike'
id: 4 name: 'Hybrid'

bike_categories
id: 1 bike_id: 1 :category_id: 2 # Womens, Mountain Bike
id: 2 bike_id: 1 :category_id: 3 

id: 3 bike_id: 2 :category_id: 2 # Womens, Hybrid
id: 4 bike_id: 2 :category_id: 4
```

In my filter if i choose `Womens` and `Mountain Bikes` i get all bikes with the categories `Womens, Mountain Bikes`, so in this example just the one result.

However I then would like to go one step further and select another category, `hybrid` (so i would select filters `Womens, Mountain Bikes, Hybrid`) and would like all bikes that have either `Womens, Mountain Bikes` and `Womens, Hybrid`, so in this instance I should get the 2 results returned

How could i modify this query to allow for this ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you will find your query will return bikes which are EITHER "womens bikes" or "mountian bikes" - as you only have categories in the test data against bike 1 any query can only return one bike - try adding a mens mountian bike and a women hybrid to your test data and see what happens

Comment: apologies, there was a typo there, have updated question. when i select 3 filter params i get no results

Comment: I think you would need to split it into two attributes to get what you want - gender (mens|womens) and bike_type (mountian bike|hybrid)

Comment: would that mean running two separate queries and then merging the results ?

Comment: No - Your query can join to multiple associations `.joins(:genders, :bike_types)` and you can include multiple where clauses `.where(bike_types: { name: 'Mountian Bike' }).where(genders: {name: "Womens'})`

Comment: If bikes are always either mens or womens, you could put the gender in the Bike class as a boolean field. Depends whether some could be classified as gender neutral!

Comment: @IanKenney ah right, so don't have all the categories in one model, split them out into `gender` and `bike_type` as you have stated

Comment: would i also then save the `gender` id and `bike_type` id in my `bike_categories` model ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used something along the following lines to allow filtering of search results by multiple attributes

```
# style for Mountian Bike etc.
class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bike_styles
  has_many :bikes, through: :bike_styles
end

class BikeStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bike
  belongs_to :style
end

# gender for Womens, Mens etc. 
# (or maybe there is a better name if you have girls / boys as well)
class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bike_genders
  has_many :bikes, through: :bike_genders
end

class BikeGender < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bike
  belongs_to :gender
end

class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bike_styles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :styles, through: :bike_styles

  has_many :bike_genders, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :genders, through: :bike_genders

  # repeat for other searchable attributes ( e.g. frame size )
  # has_many :bike_sizes, dependent: :destroy
  # has_many :sizes, through: :bike_sizes

  # returns filtered results based on the params, call as follows:
  #   Bikes.search style: "Mountian Bike", gender: "Mens"    
  #   Bikes.search style: "Mountian Bike"
  #   Bikes.search gender: "Mens"
  def self.search(params)
    filtered = params[:collection] || self
    filtered = style_filter(filtered, params[:style])
    filtered = gender_filter(filtered, params[:gender])
    filtered
  end

  # filters by style (if one is provided)  
  def self.style_filter(filtered, style)
     filtered = filtered.joins(:styles).where(styles: {name: style}) unless style.blank?
     filtered
   end

  # filters by gender (if one is provided)  
  def self.gender_filter(filtered, gender)
     filtered = filtered.joins(:genders).where(genders: {name: gender}) unless gender.blank?
     filtered
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Ian for taking the time to write this up. gives me something to refer to at least and learn from. When i am passing the params through to the search method, are they just passed as an array `['Mens', 'Mountain Bikes', 'Hybrid']` for example

Comment: or do i send in a hash ?

Comment: params would be a hash for example :  `{gender: "mens", style: ["Hybrid",  "Mountian Bike"]}` - you would only need to pass in the keys you wanted to filter on

Comment: have you got 5 mins for a chat please ?

Comment: well actually i guess my question is if i had the following bikes  `gender: Mens, style: Mountain Bikes`, `gender: Mens, style: hybrid` and I had the filters `{ gender: 'Mens', style: ['Mountain Biles', 'Hybrid']}`. Would only those two bikes be returned, does that make sense ?

Comment: @Richlewis - I can chat now if it helps

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/43195/search-functionality-rails-4?tab=general